# Using BeautifulSoup for scraping Yahoo Finance returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape this website and get the price from it.
When I run my code I always get `None`, I have tried with `.find` and `.find_all` but the result is always the same:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')


stock_price = soup.find('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)')

# I should get 8,531.30
print(stock_price)
```

I see that `'span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'` is dynamic, but then I have tried to get unique div thats above:

```
stock_price = soup.find_all('div', class_='D(ib) Va(m) Maw(65%) Ov(h)')
```

or:

```
stock_price = soup.find_all('div', class_='D(ib) Mend(20px)')
```

These 2 `div`s are not dynamic, only two `span`s inside them are dynamic, why cant I get my elements?

I have watched this tutorial and they do not use `Chrome Selenium`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rONhdonaWUo

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The biggest mistake you're doing is that yahoo has a finance API & you're trying to scrape it

Comment: but since you want to understand, The response you get in BS4 is the same as if you right click the page & *VIEW PAGE SOURCE*, Which is not the same as *Inspect Element*

Answer (score 0):

```
class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"
```

It is just dynamically generated clas by javascript so you need to get attached to another attribute or to another tag.
Also, remember you this attribute must be unique on the page if not find() return just first coincidence

Comment: I have tried that, I have tried to get div thats above, but the result is the same

Comment: I think every attribute where we have (px) is dynamic for different browsers, screen sizes etc,  that means python gets this data in another view. You can look at how it looks in python just save the page into some file..
Also we can get div by id="quote-header-info" and try to parse it in deeper level